# gradle : how to configure all the subproject plugin in the same place?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

My gradle project have multiple sub-project who all use the same plugins. One of this plugins need a resolutionStrategy.

My issue is, if I put the apply plugin in the subproject config of the root project, the pluginManagement/resolutionStrategy/eachPlugin method is not called and the build fail (the pluginManagement/resolutionStrategy is still called, it's just the eachPlugin who isn't)

how can I fix it?

It work if I put it in the subproject/graddle.build, but my need is to configure the "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform" in the **root/config/subprojects step.**

my code :

root/gradle.build

```
configure(subprojects){
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50"
        }
    }
this.apply plugin:"java"
this.apply plugin:"org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform" version "1.3.50"

}
```

settings.xml

```
pluginManagement {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
        if (requested.id.id == "kotlin-multiplatform") {

            useModule("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
        }
        if (requested.id.id == "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") {
            useModule("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
        }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    gradlePluginPortal()

    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    maven { url = 'https://dl.bintray.com/russhwolf/multiplatform-settings' }
}
```

}